# selection of values without spaces

Tags: sql-server

how can I fix my query select, namely I have a problem when looking for a value without white space, for example with this code it gives me the value "nr":

```
Select TOP(1) nr from tabele1 where Tel LIKE  '%00 55 55 55 55%'
```

while this query I get in the code gives me the result:

```
Select TOP(1) nr from tabele1 where Tel LIKE  '%0055555555%'
```

how can i repair the sql query above ie without white space, that i can get the same value "nr" with it. Thank you

```
sql format Tel :   Tel [varchar](25) NOT NULL --phone nummber
```

Comment: Format tel before testing.

Comment: i agree with @P.Salmon. but you can user `REPLACE` too

Comment: @P.Salmon I'm doing a search based on my phone number ("Tel"), I've added the format Tel

Comment: No kidding. Why not replace(tel,' ','') =